# Are you notified when a tweet you retweeted is retweeted by someone else?

Tags: twitter, retweet

If I retweet a tweet that has been retweetd by a user on Twitter I do not follow, will that user then get a notification saying that I have "Retweeted a tweet they retweeted"?

For example,

1. Alice posts
2. Bob retweets Alice
3. Carlos retweets Bob's retweet of Alice's tweet

Does Bob get told or notified that Carlos retweeted a tweet Bob retweeted?

Comment: Let's test it. Go to my profile https://twitter.com/pythonerd and RT something I RT-ed. Then you can know for sure if I get a notification.

Comment: A posts. B retweets A. C retweets A, but does not follow A. Does A get told C retweeted them? Is that it?

Comment: No, A posts, B rewteets, C retweets B's reweet but does B get told that C retweeted them? Sorry, it's very confusing!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this happens. And you can be notified of it.

In [Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/notifications), there is an "Activity related to your Retweets" section. One of the options is:

- My Retweets are retweeted

When it happens, in your Interactions section, you will see:

> **Person** retweeted your Retweet

If you have email notifications set up, you will get an email along the lines of

> **Friend** retweeted one of your Retweets!
>
> **Your name**,
> Your Retweet got retweeted!